# calculate slope of lines between nodes?

Tags: qgis, road, slope

I need to calculate the mean slope of roads between nodes with QGIS. I have a DEM and a vector (*PostGIS*) with the roads, nodes are additionally displayed as point shape and also contain an elevation field derived from DEM:

[image]

I am looking for the mean slope between those nodes which are connected with a line.

As there are many roads to calculate (see the picture below), I need a workflow which processes all calculations at once.Either output as raster (with slope values on the roads and NoData for others) or shapefiles containing the the slope are useful for my purpose.

How can I do this?

[image]

I have a ArcGIS solution in mind (3D Analyst / interpolate shape), but I'd prefer a QGIS / open source solution!

I tried the *Profile Tool Plugin*, which only processes one line at once. Further, I was thinking of using a slope raster and failed because of the direction of the slope (contour line streets).

I was looking for other approaches, but it didn't work or I didn't understand them, e.g.:

- [calculate slope for a road network](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30811/calculate-slope-for-a-road-network)
- [Computing the slope of a road using DEM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239704/computing-the-slope-of-a-road-using-dem)
- [Slope, in which direction?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235005/slope-in-which-direction)
- [Calculating slope direction in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208636/calculating-slope-direction-in-qgis/211304)
- [Determining gradient of road segment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32580/determining-gradient-of-road-segment)
- [Calculating average slope from line using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246098/calculating-average-slope-from-line-using-qgis)
- http://youarealegend.blogspot.ch/2012/07/computing-roads-slopes-with-qgis.html

Answer (score 2):

Given DEM (raster) and Linea (SHP) calculate the slope on each segment of line

1) Explode Linea--->Segment
2) Field calculator
define two float field
Z_end_point
raster_value('Lake_100m',1,make_point(x(end_point($geometry)),y(end_point($geometry))))

Z_start_point
raster_value('Lake_100m',1,make_point(x(start_point($geometry)),y(start_point($geometry))))

then 
slope= Z_end_point-Z_start_point/lenght($geometry)*100

Comment: The last expression is incorrect. The right expression should be slope = (Z_end_point-Z_start_point)/lenght($geometry)*100

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a python script. Basically, for each line, you iterate the nodes. for each pair of nodes, you sample the elevation from the raster, and then you calculate the slope.

My plugin "Walking time", uses a very similar approach. maybe you can read its code and adapt:

https://github.com/SrNetoChan/WalkingTime/blob/master/walkingtime.py#L160

Comment: yeah I tried your pretty cool plugin! But unfortunately I don't use QGIS enough to understand python.

Comment: There is a QGis plugin that can do this: Road slope calculator.